# Why does MODIFY AUTO_INCREMENT need to rebuild the table?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, alter-table

We have loaded several tables (hundreds of millions of rows each) but the following query requires the entire table to be rewritten (the type is exactly the same apart from the `AUTO_INCREMENT`):

```
ALTER TABLE sales MODIFY id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Is this just a huge oversight by MySQL or does it fundamentally change the format the data on disk?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the AUTO_INCREMENT characteristic of a column cannot be done as an online DDL change. Even when I try to request it explicitly:

```
mysql> alter table sales modify column id bigint not null auto_increment, 
  ALGORITHM=INPLACE;

ERROR 1846 (0A000): ALGORITHM=INPLACE is not supported. 
Reason: Cannot change column type INPLACE. Try ALGORITHM=COPY.
```

This case of changing the column definition seems to count as a change to the column type (based on the error message).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid says:

> Change column data type... Only supports ALGORITHM=COPY

In MySQL 5.7, changing the type of a column is still required to rebuild the table, except in one case: increasing VARCHAR length is allowed as an INPLACE change.

You aren't the only one to think that it should be allowed to change the AUTO_INCREMENT property without doing a table restructure: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72109